# beego session save struct

Tags: session, go, gob

I'm giving up after few weeks, can't figure out a way to encode/decode a struct in session between **beego** apps.

Question:
How to store properly in session a struct say [`app1/models/User`](https://github.com/TalLannder/app1/blob/master/models/user.go) and decode it in other process/app to [`app2/models/User`](https://github.com/TalLannder/app2/blob/master/models/user.go) without importing anything from app1?

in app2 we do know the struct structure:

```
struct {
  Name string
  Age    int
}
```

I've put together two examples for app1 and app2, not sure if they are of any help since in app2 I cant properly decode the struct :(.

https://github.com/TalLannder/app1

https://github.com/TalLannder/app2